# How to check if "unsorted version" of a list already exists in the set?

Tags: python, list, sorting, append

I want to generate a list of lists. Each sub-list will be generated by sampling from `range(100)`. I need to make sure lists that are identical (i.e. have the exact same elements) but have different sorting do not exist in the main list (i.e. I do not want `[1,2,3]` and `[2,1,3]` in the main list at the same time). This is what I have written:

```
import random as rd
my_list = []
while len(my_list) < 50:
    p = rd.sample(range(100), 10)
    if p not in my_list: my_list.append(p)
```

The issue is `if p not in my_list` does not do the job as it does not consider `[1,2,3]` and `[2,1,3]` identical. I thought of doing something like this:

```
my_list = []
while len(my_list) < 50:
    p = rd.sample(range(100), 10)
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if set(p) != set(my_list[i]): my_list.append(p)
```

But it seems this gets stuck in the first loop and the program never ends. I was wondering if there is a simple way of doing this in Python?

Comment: `if set(p) == set(my_list[i]): my_list.append(p)` says to append `p` if it *is* already in the list.

Comment: That was a typo! Thanks for catching it!

Comment: The new version will append a copy of `p` for every current element of `my_list` that doesn't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the generated list inside the (*if* conditional from the) *for* loop. 
**But**, given the fact that *my_list* is empty at the beginning:

- The *for* loop is a *no op*
- The *if* is never executed
- Thus no element is appended to *my_list*, so it never gets modified
- You get an infinite loop (or you're in a deadlock kind of situation)

To fix it, refactor a bit your loop ([[Python 3.Docs]: Compound statements - The for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)) to:

```py
for existing in my_list:
    if set(p) == set(existing):
        break
else:
    my_list.append(p)
```

It runs in less than *0.1* seconds.

To improve things even more, store the sets in a separate list (to avoid unnecessarily recalculating them waaay too many times than needed) and use that for inclusion test:

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import random
import time


def main():
    final_list = list()
    sentinel_list = list()
    start_time = time.time()
    count = 0
    while len(sentinel_list) < 50:
        inner_list = random.sample(range(100), 10)
        inner_set = set(inner_list)
        if inner_set not in sentinel_list:
            final_list.append(inner_list)
            sentinel_list.append(inner_set)
        count += 1
    del sentinel_list
    print("{:d} element list generated in {:d} iterations".format(len(final_list), count))
    print("Took {:.3f} seconds".format(time.time() - start_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056317300]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.07.03_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> 50 element list generated in 50 iterations
> Took 0.003 seconds
>
> Done.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic isn't quite right—you only want to add something to the list when it's not already in it. Here's how to do that by using a `for` loop's option `else` clause which will only execute if the `break` is never executed. How this works is described in the [documentaton](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) of the `for` statement.

```
my_list = []
for p in [1,2,3], [3,2,1], [4,5,6]:
    for c in my_list:
        if set(p) == set(c):
            break
    else:
        my_list.append(p)

print(my_list)  # -> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

It's also inefficient to convert each combination to a `set` more than once, so you can take that part out of the loop:

```
my_list = []
for p in [1,2,3], [3,2,1], [4,5,6]:
    set_p = set(p)  # do this here
    for c in my_list:
        if set_p == set(c):
            break
    else:
        my_list.append(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers seem to have missed the non-quadratic solution of keeping a set of frozensets:

```
def unique_without_order_retaining_order(L):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for item in L:
        f = frozenset(item)
        if f not in seen:
           seen.add(f)
           output.append(item)
    return output
```

This can be adapted to be a generator.